# How do i view and access my windows 7 laptop from my ubuntu desktop?

Tags: windows, display, monitor

The desktop has 2 outputs for monitor display: Can I plug in a vga chord from my laptop to the desktop? and control (the mouse and keyboard) the laptop from my ubuntu desktop?

I was thinking of putting the output video from my windows 7 laptop to one of the ubuntu workspaces?

The laptop only has a vga output. I am not sure the desktop can pick up the signal from the laptop and output it in my desktop monitor.

what are my options if I load ubuntu on my laptop as well? will it be easier and what do I have to do?

I tried synergy but my desktop uses my laptop as a wireless hotspot, so they both have the same IP, therefore it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics card connectors are just outputs for the video signal. You can only plug a monitor (or any display) to them.

You can't use them as inputs for another source (eg: another computer), let alone take over the mouse and keyboard.

You have the following options:

1. Buy a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). It lets you switch one keyboard/video/mouse between multiple computers
2. Remote desktop with [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC), so you can always keep a window to your other PC
3. Invest in a router/access-point and go with synergy (if it doesn't work with the laptop in hotspot mode)
4. If your monitor has multiple inputs, connect the two computers to the monitor and switch from one another

Comment: thank you, I finally found the reason why... #3 works for me thouh, maybe because im using my laptop with virtual router still running windows. would be nice to use ubuntu 100% though since it seems to run faster.